# Remove items form the list in React js

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a To-do app & I am not able to write the code for deleting the elements of the list when we click them. I want the specific item to delete when a user clicks on it

```
class Todo extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={todos:[]};
    }

    save() {
      var todos = [...this.state.todos];
      todos.push(this.newText.value);
      this.setState({todos});
    }

    remove{

    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div className="list">
              <h1> TO-DO List</h1>
              <input type="text" ref={(ip) => {this.newText = ip}}/>
              <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved">Save
              </button>
              <ul>
                {this.state.todos.map(function(todo) {
                      return <li>{todo}</li>

                 })}

              </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass on the index of the todo and then remove that using the slice function in javascript like

```
remove(e, index){
      var todos = [...this.state.todos];
      todos.slice(index, 1);
      this.setState({todos})
}
```

```js
class Todo extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={todos:[]};
    }

    save() {
      var todos = [...this.state.todos];
      todos.push(this.newText.value);
      this.setState({todos});
    }

    deleteTodo(index){
        console.log(index)
         var todos = [...this.state.todos];
         todos.splice(index, 1)
         this.setState({todos})
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div className="list">
              <h1> TO-DO List</h1>
              <input type="text" ref={(ip) => {this.newText = ip}}/>
              <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved">Save
              </button>
              <ul>
                {this.state.todos.map(function(todo, index) {
                      return <li key={index} onClick={this.deleteTodo.bind(this, index)}>{todo}</li>

                 }.bind(this))}

              </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Todo/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: There is a typo in `remove` function: Instead `slice` you means `splice`. Please, fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Define a `onClick` method with each todo elements, and **bind the name** also, like this:

```
{this.state.todos.map((todo) => { //use arrow function to bind the context
       return <li onClick={this._deleteTodo.bind(this, todo)}>{todo}</li>
})}
```

Whenever you click on any todo items it will pass the name of that to `onClick` function, now use `indexOf` to calculate the index of that item in `array`, and use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=control) to delete that from the list, like ethis:

```
_deleteTodo(value){
    let todos = this.state.todos.slice();  //create a copy of that array first
    todos.splice(todos.indexOf(value), 1);
    this.setState({todos});  
}
```

Check the working example:

```js
class Todo extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={todos:[]};
    }

    save() {
      var todos = [...this.state.todos];
      todos.push(this.newText.value);
      this.setState({todos});
    }

    _deleteTodo(value){
       let todos = this.state.todos.slice();  
       todos.splice(todos.indexOf(value), 1);
       this.setState({todos});  
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div className="list">
              <h1> TO-DO List</h1>
              <input type="text" ref={(ip) => {this.newText = ip}}/>
              <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved">Save
              </button>
              <ul>
                {this.state.todos.map((todo) => {
                    return <li onClick={this._deleteTodo.bind(this, todo)}>{todo}</li>
                })}
              </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Todo/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```