# how to remove item in todo list using React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, key

I am using React to create a to do list app, in my app when I click x button to remove an Item and using console.log to check current array, I can see the array is updated correctly with the Item I want to remove removed from the list of array, but the Dom only renders the Item I want to remove instead of the whole array

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

class TodoList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            todoList:[],
            todo:''
        }
    };

    onValueChange=(e)=>{
        const todo=e.target.value;
        this.setState({todo})
    };

    removeItem=(props)=>{
        this.setState({todoList:this.state.todoList.splice(props,1)})
        console.log(this.state.todoList)
    };

    onSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const {todoList,todo}=this.state
        this.setState({todoList:[...todoList,todo]})
        this.setState({todo:''})
        console.log(this.state.todoList)
    };

    render(){
        const myList=this.state.todoList.map((todo,index)=>(
            <li key={index}>
                {todo}
                <button onClick={()=>this.removeItem(index)}>x</button>
            </li>
        ))
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        value={this.state.todo}
                        onChange={this.onValueChange}
                        autoFocus
                        placeholder='todo'
                    />
                </form>
                <ol>
                    {myList}
                </ol>
            </div>
        )
    };
};

ReactDom.render(<TodoList/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

this is the picture

[image]

in the picture you can see that the console shows the array with item '5' removed, but the screen only show the item '5' instead of the items 1 to 4

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893508/remove-items-form-the-list-in-react-js/43893804#43893804

Comment: splice returns the removed items. splice first and then assign

Comment: dont check array with console.log! setState is async method and you cant see state mutation immediately after setState. You can use method like setTimeout(() => console.log(this.state)) or print state in componentDidUpdate function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your `removeItem`

```
removeItem = (props)=> {
    this.state.todoList.splice(props, 1)
    this.setState({todoList: this.state.todoList})
    console.log(this.state.todoList)
};
```

[`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method modify the array in place.

**Return Value**

> An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is
>   removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are
>   removed, an empty array is returned.

Answer (score 4):

[In React: mutating `state` directly is discouraged.](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data)

Best practice would be to [`clone` using a `spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the result.

```
removeItem = (index) => {
  return this.setState({todoList: [...this.state.todoList].splice(index, 1)})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Splice function doesn't return you the final array, instead it mutates the array, on which the operation is being performed.

It is good if you extract `todoList` out of this.state and perform splice operation.

```
removeItem=(props)=>{
    const { todoList } = this.state;
    todoList.splice(props, 1);
    this.setState({
        todoList,
    });
    console.log(this.state.todoList)
};
```

The above answer just works fine. But this is just a cleaner implementation of the same.