# react js delete handler removes the 1st index in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, handler

The problem is any item button click will delete the 1st index item in the array.

I looked at these resources on handling deleting an item in an array in react.

- [How to remove item in todo list using React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902921/how-to-remove-item-in-todo-list-using-react)
- [Removing element from array in component state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527385/removing-element-from-array-in-component-state)
- [React Binding Patterns](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

I've tried changing how my handler is called in TodoList and TodoItemLIst and that causes the handler not to fire on click. I've tried different methods of binding the handler - adding a param has no effect on it -bind(this) breaks it & isn't necessary because I'm using a function.

I've tried setting state different ways using a filter method. No change happens...

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    todoItems: prevState.todoItems.filter(i => i !== index)
}));
```

I'm not understanding where/what the problem is.

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = { 
  value: '',
  listItemValue: props.value || '',
  todoItems:  [
    {id: _.uniqueId(), item: 'Learn React.'},
    {id: _.uniqueId(), item: 'Improve JS skills.'},
    {id: _.uniqueId(), item: 'Play with kittens.'}
  ]
};
}

handleChange = (event) => {
let value = event.target.value;
this.setState({
  value: this.state.value,
  listItemValue: value
});
}

handleSubmit = (event) =>{
event.preventDefault();

this.setState({
  value: '',
  listItemValue: ''
});
}

addTodoItem = () => {
let todoItems = this.state.todoItems.slice(0);

  todoItems.push({
    id: _.uniqueId(),
    item: this.state.listItemValue
  });

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    todoItems: [
        ...prevState.todoItems,
        {
          id: _.uniqueId(),
          item: this.state.listItemValue
        }]
  }))
};

deleteTodoItem = (index) => {
let todoItems = this.state.todoItems.slice();
todoItems.splice(index, 1);

this.setState({ 
  todoItems
});
}

render() {

return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    <TodoListForm name="todo"
                  onClick={ ()=>this.addTodoItem() }
                  onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }
                  handleChange={ this.handleChange }
                  value={ this.state.listItemValue } />
    <TodoList onClick={ ()=>this.deleteTodoItem() }
              todoItems={ this.state.todoItems }/>
  </div>
);
}
}

const TodoList = (props) => {
const todoItem = props.todoItems.map((todo) => {
   return (
    <TodoListItem  onClick={ props.onClick }  
                   key={ todo.id }
                   id={ todo.id }
                   item={ todo.item }/>
   );
});
return (
<ul className="TodoList">
    {todoItem}
</ul>
);
}

const TodoListItem = (todo, props) => {
return (

    <li className="TodoListItem">
        <div className="TodoListItem__Item">{todo.item}
        <span className="TodoListItem__Icon"></span>
        <button onClick={ todo.onClick } 
                type="button" 
                className="TodoListItem__Btn">&times;</button>
        </div>
    </li>
)
};
```

Comment: In the `deleteTodoItem` method, try just 'let todoItems = this.state.todoItems.slice(0, -1);` and remove the call to `splice()`.

Comment: And in addTodoItems, you can use `concat` to avoid using `slice`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs#26254086

Comment: And this should be easy to solve using breakpoints and the dev tools.

Comment: @Nick That was it. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the deleteTodoItem method, try just

```
let todoItems = this.state.todoItems.slice(0, -1);
```

and remove the call to `splice()`.