# grid-row-gap affecting divs with display: none

Tags: css, css-grid

I am currently using CSS grid, and I'm using the `grid-row-gap` and `column-row-gap` many places. My problem is that when doing media queries, and some elements/divs are not to be shown at smaller resolution I usually just set them to `display: none`. However, if I'm not mistaken, even though the element can be seen, the row or column gap feature still applies on the "hidden" element.

Is there any way to fix this, or am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT:

Okay, it seems like `display: none` don't affect the grid-row-gap - which makes sense. But I found a small workaround by removing the grid-gap and adding a padding instead when the resolution changes. And that seems to do the trick.

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: show us the code

Comment: This is the standard behaviour, Grid-rows/columns are not elements and will be there **whether there is content in them or not**.  Depending on your code, you might need to rethink your layout, If you create a demo in s a Stack Snippet we might be able to help.

Comment: You don't remove grid tracks with `display: none`. That just removes the item. Since the tracks are still there, the grid gaps remain, as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50218855/3597276

Comment: I'm so sad this doesn't work :-(

Comment: NVM it does work with grid-auto-columns

Comment: @Simon_Weaver NVM is does not work with flexbox, back to sadness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to fix this [...]?

One simple fix when applying `display: none;` to child elements in a CSS grid, is to remember to alter the parent grid accordingly to take account of the fact that those child elements are no longer displayed.

**Working Example:**

```css
body > div {
display: inline-grid;
grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
grid-row-gap: 6px;
grid-column-gap: 12px;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
margin-right: 24px;
border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

div div {
border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

body > div:hover div:nth-of-type(n+7) {
display: none;
}

body > div:nth-of-type(2):hover {
grid-template-rows: auto auto;
height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>

<div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

In both the CSS Grids above the final three child elements are removed from display on `:hover`. But in the second grid (only) the height of the parent and the number of `grid-template-rows` are also reduced, thus avoiding displaying a gap which the non-displayed child elements used to occupy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you use [`grid-auto-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns) (or [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows)) because the column definitions are dynamic, therefore no column exists if the item is hidden.

In this example I'm using `grid-auto-flow: column` which is sort of similar to `flex-direction: row` in this example. It's easier to visualize what's going on if they are columns vs. rows.

Note: `grid-auto-flow` is supported in IE, but `*-auto-columns` is.

Important: Don't confuse this with `grid-template-columns: auto` !

```css
.outer-container
{
    background: yellow;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

.container
{
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item
{
    background: steelblue;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    color: white;
}

.item.hidden
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="item">Item 1</div>
     <div class="item">Item 2</div>
     <div class="item hidden">Item 3 (hidden)</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```